# How can I determine data type during runtime in C++?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have a class B which derives from A:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    class iterator; // Defined fully

    iterator begin ()
    {
        // Returns a pointer to the first element
    }
    iterator end ()
    {   
        // Returns a pointer to the last element
    }
}
template <class T>
class B : public A
{
    // It automatically inherits the iterator
}

template <typename InputIterator>
void foo (InputIterator first,InputIterator last)
{
    // Some code to infer whether it is of type A or B
}
```

Now some function say `foo()` is called using `B::begin()` at one time and sometime with `A::begin()`.

I need to determine type during runtime to infer type and set some flag variables. How do I do this? I tried using `typeinfo()` but it returns the same value for both the iterators.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You have `InputIterator` - that's already the type. Both iterators *are* the same type. Are you asking how to distinguish `B::iterator` from `A::iterator`?

Comment: If you need to run different code based on different types why not make two overloads that do what is needed and then call a common function?

Comment: I need to infer whether the argument passed is of A::iterator or B::iterator

Comment: Are you looking for [`is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) to check whether `InputIterator` is the same as `A::iterator` or `B::iterator`?

Comment: @NathanOliver If I have 10 parameters then I have to make 1024 functions which is impossible

Comment: I feel this would be a poor design pattern that goes against both what inheritance and iterators were designed for. Ignoring that, the only way I can see to do it would be to have the iterators hold some pointer to their container and have some virtual function that can distinguish `A` and `B`

Comment: @nwp Yours is the closest to what I want..but there is a slight problem...both classes are templated...so how do I infer type now ?

Comment: `A::iterator` and `B::iterator` are the same type, so it's not surprising that you can't tell them apart.

Comment: why you need a runtime type checking in the first place? Surely you can find a solution which doesn't require it. Smells like poor design to me

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini In my code..the user may give a device_vector (A here) or shared_vector (B here)...I have to used "Shared Memory" in GPU only if he passes shared_vector...So this is a very real life problem

Comment: How about a virtual `Type()` method in your iterator classes that would return, for instance, an enumerator of `Type_A` or `Type_B`? Then you could simply call the `Type()` method from whichever iterator you are using, as in: `first.Type()`.

Comment: @Logicrat I am writing class B and I can modify class A

Comment: Could you make a class derived from A that takes a template parameter. Have the template parameter be used to instantiate a templated iterator. Then have B derive from that using a different template type than that used by anyone instantiating an A (maybe typedef A<t> to be used with a certain type)? A container of pointers to the non-templated base class should still be able to hold all of the objects. You should be able to use `is_same` to compare.

Comment: @PRP so why don't you use two overloads to tell out which is which. Or just use typeof() (you need boost library to do so). Or just use typeid (C++11)

Comment: XY problem? Why do you think you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From library type_traits you can use some type magic:
is_base_of - returns true if Base is base of Derived.
is_same - returns true if A is the same type as B.
Everything with type_traits can be found here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/?kw=type_traits

They are not so runtime, it's only some magic with structs and templates, C++ does not support type as data by default. If you want so you can use Boost library, it does support types as I know.

UPD:
As comments under the question mentioned A::iterator is absolutely the same with B::iterator, so without looking at classes they are the same memory chunk.
So solution (maybe) is to create a little different function, what depends on classes actually:

```
 template <typename LeftClass, typename RightClass>
 void foo (LeftClass left, RightClass right)
 { 
     if(is_same<LeftClass, RightClass>::value)
     {

     }
 //Or that
     if(is_same<LeftClass, A>::value && is_same<RightClass, A>::value)
 }
```

Just don't forget to make this "friend" with classes.

Comment: The problem is that in `foo(...)` there is no `A` or `B` there is only `InputIterator`

Comment: Ow... Well there is also is_convertible or is_same... Seems I still barely can understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

`typeinfo()` returns the same value, because both `A::begin()` and `B::begin()` give you a value *of the same type*.

You should either have `B::iterator` inherit from `A::iterator` or have a special function in your iterator that returns a reference/pointer to it's container (which is then either of type `A` or type `B`).